# Stopping a Service Reference using the XmlSerializerFormatAttribute from serializing partial class's properties

Tags: c#, soap

I'm using partial classes to extend a service references functionality.

The service reference is using XmlSerializerFormatAttribute for its serialization.

Now in one of the partial classes, I have a property with an interface object. Which is causing the following error to be thrown when accessed.

```
Cannot serialize member Exact.Exnet.EAFusion.MagentoService.Version_1_9_1.complexFilter.Value of type     Exact.Exnet.EAFusion.MagentoService.Interfaces.IAssociativeEntity, see inner exception for more details.
```

Inner Exception

```
"Cannot serialize member Exact.Exnet.EAFusion.MagentoService.Version_1_9_1.complexFilter.Value of type Exact.Exnet.EAFusion.MagentoService.Interfaces.IAssociativeEntity because it is an interface."
```

XmlIgnore has been suggested by many people but the error is still thrown when implemented in the follow way;

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IAssociativeEntity Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set 
        {
            this.value = (associativeEntity)value;
        }
    }
```

The partial class is shown below;

```
public partial class complexFilter : IComplexFilter
{
    public string Key
    {
        get { return this.key; }
        set { this.key = value; }
    }

    public IAssociativeEntity Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set 
        {
            this.value = (associativeEntity)value;
        }
    }
}
```

the Value property is the one causing the issues.

Below is the class is the ServiceReference that my class is a partial class of.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Magento")]
public partial class complexFilter : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string keyField;

    private associativeEntity valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string key {
        get {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set {
            this.keyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("key");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public associativeEntity value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("value");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problematic member in a part of the partial class that you can edit? or is it in a generated file?

Comment: Editable, I've created the partial class.

Comment: You mention soap in the tags; have you tried `[SoapIgnore]` ?

Comment: also: `[NonSerialized]` (fields only; use `[field:NonSerialized]` for things like automatically implemented events

Comment: I should note: if this is actually using `XmlSerializer`, as suggested, then for me: adding `[XmlIgnore]` to the `public  IAssociativeEntity Value` - makes it work fine

Comment: I've previously tried [XmlIgnore] and the error message was still thrown. 

I've edited the OP to include the SOAP code of the class.

Comment: Pasting the **exact error message**, including any `.InnerException` (and any `.InnerException` on the `.InnerException`, etc) would be really useful...

Comment: Error message has been added to the OP.

Comment: You **need** to post the inner exception text, and so on; serializers are notorious for burying the actual problem several layers down. But to confirm: you definitely had `[XmlIgnore]` on the `Value` property? For reference, I get `There was an error reflecting type 'complexFilter'.`, `Cannot serialize member 'complexFilter.Value' of type 'IAssociativeEntity', see inner exception for more details.`, `Cannot serialize member complexFilter.Value of type IAssociativeEntity because it is an interface.`

Comment: InnerException has been added along with the implementation for [XmlIgnore]

Comment: Well, that's odd; by every usual trick, what you have: should work.